# Unable to capture events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to capture the events in jQuery. Below is the snippet I am using.

```
console.log(selectElement);
      selectElement.on('selected', function(event) {
      console.log('Value ' + event.selected + ' selected.');
});
```

Below is the output in browser console.

```
jQuery.fn.init [select.coral-Select-select.coral-Select-select--native, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: coral-multifield-item.coral3-Multifield-item, selector: "select[name="./selectlevel"]"]
```

I am able to capture the select element but event handler for selected is not working. Please let me know if any other information you need.
[image]

Please refer the js fiddle link. HTML may not be accurate as these are coral ui libraries.
https://jsfiddle.net/vivekdhiman23/Le296qw1/2/

Comment: There is no `selected` event by default, unless this is specified in some third party library which you've not mentioned

Comment: should be `.on('change'` instead

Answer (score 1):

You may use "change" event on this elemenet and get the value. Example:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

You need jQuery for this. $ will be undefined in pure javascript. The jsfiddle example has the same console error.
In your code, you need to use this:

```
$('coral-multifield[data-granite-coral-multifield-name="./navtwoitems"]').each(function() {
            $(this).find("coral-multifield-item").each(function() {
                    var selectElement = $(this).find('select[name="./selectlevel"]');

                    selectElement.on("change", function() {
                      alert( "Handler for "+ $(this).attr("name") +" called." );
                    });
            });
      });
```

With this, you will see the select tag's name in the console. 
I modified the jsfiddle a bit. You can check it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Le296qw1/8/

I hope this will usefull for you.

Comment: Can you add you html code pls? Or an example code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you need pure javascript, or can you use some jQuery vertion?

Comment: jquery will be fine